# Inline with containing complex function

Tags: c++, inline

Let's take this for example:

```
Class TestClass {
public:
  int functionInline();
  int functionComplex();
};

inline int TestClas::functionInline()
{
  // a single instruction
  return functionComplex();
}

int TestClas::functionComplex()
{
  /* many complex
     instructions
  */
}

void myFunc()
{
  TestClass testVar;

  testVar.functionInline();
}
```

Suposing that all coments are in fact lines of code that are single line or many and complex lines of code. The equivalent code would be (after compilation):

```
void myFunc()
{
  TestClass testVar;

  // a single instruction
  return functionComplex();
}
```

or would be:

```
void myFunc()
{
  TestClass testVar;

  // a single instruction

  /* many complex
     instructions
  */
}
```

In other words, would a normal function be inserted inline if called inside an inline function or not?

Comment: Probably the first one, but it depends on many many factors that are hard to predict, and of course varies widely across compilers, optimization options, etc. i.e. A compiler deciding to replace a function call with the function's body has almost nothing to do with the `inline` keyword, which is an abstract language concept related to the [*One Definition Rule*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Answer (score 1):

If the compiler can see that the function is not called anywhere else (e.g. it is `static` in the case of a free function), then at least gcc has inlined it for a long time.

Of course, this also assumes the compiler can actually "see" the source code of the function - only if you use "whole program optimisation" (available in at least MS and GCC compilers), does it inline functions that aren't either in the source file or headers included in the source.

Obviously, inlining a "large" function has very little benefit (because the overhead of making the call is such a small portion of the total runtime), and if the function gets called more than once (or "may be called more than once" by not being `static`), the compiler will almost certainly not inline a "large" function.

In summary: maybe the large function is inline, but quite likely not.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the assembly code that I generated both for VC++ 2010 and g++.
Both the compilers dont actually treat any of the function as inline in this example.

**Code:**

```
class TestClass {
public:
  int functionInline();
  int functionComplex();
};

inline int TestClass::functionInline()
{
  // a single instruction
  return functionComplex();
}

int TestClass::functionComplex()
{
  /* many complex
     instructions
  */
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    TestClass t;
    t.functionInline();
    return 0;
}
```

**VC++ 2010:**

```
int main(){
01372E50  push        ebp  
01372E51  mov         ebp,esp  
01372E53  sub         esp,0CCh  
01372E59  push        ebx  
01372E5A  push        esi  
01372E5B  push        edi  
01372E5C  lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
01372E62  mov         ecx,33h  
01372E67  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
01372E6C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
    TestClass t;
    t.functionInline();
01372E6E  lea         ecx,[t]  
01372E71  call        TestClass::functionInline (1371677h)  
    return 0;
01372E76  xor         eax,eax  
}
```

**Linux G++:**

```
main:
.LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    leaq    -1(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN9TestClass14functionInlineEv
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Both the lines

**01372E71  call  TestClass::functionInline (1371677h)**

and

**call  _ZN9TestClass14functionInlineEv**

indicate that the function **functionInline** is not inline.

Now have a look at **functionInline** assembly:

```
inline int TestClass::functionInline()
{
01372E00  push        ebp  
01372E01  mov         ebp,esp  
01372E03  sub         esp,0CCh  
01372E09  push        ebx  
01372E0A  push        esi  
01372E0B  push        edi  
01372E0C  push        ecx  
01372E0D  lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
01372E13  mov         ecx,33h  
01372E18  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
01372E1D  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
01372E1F  pop         ecx  
01372E20  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx  
  // a single instruction
  return functionComplex();
01372E23  mov         ecx,dword ptr [this]  
01372E26  call        TestClass::functionComplex (1371627h)  
}
```

Hence, **functionComplex** is not also inline.

Comment: What about when using these force keywords (__forceinline and __always_inline) that @Michael wrote about, on the functionInline()? Which one get's inline? Thanks

Comment: After checking out the __forceinline keyword usage, I found out that __forceinline  does indeed force the compiler to make the function expand inline. But in some conditions compiler can not afford the code to be inlined hence VC++ overrides __forceinline in some cases.

For more details, please visit: [msdn description of inline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx)

Comment: @CodeKirsh Considering the exact same scenario at the begining, where only the functioInline is marked to be inlined (but using __forceinline keyword instead of inline), it only expands the first function (functionInline) or both of them?

Comment: @CPJ , as per the original code, functionInline() is never inline in VC++, instead funcitonComplex() is inline.
`Warning 13 warning C4710: 'int __thiscall TestClass::functionInline(void)' : function not inlined d:\projects\practice\practice\inlinecomplex.cpp 25
Warning 14 warning C4711: function 'int __thiscall TestClass::functionComplex(void)' selected for automatic inline expansion d:\projects\practice\practice\inlinecomplex.cpp 26
`
But using __forceInline turns funcitonInline() into an inline funciton, as I get no error this time.

Answer (score 0):

No it would not be inlined. It is impossible beacause the compiler does not have available the body definition of a non-inlined function that could be located in another translation unit. I suppose normal function is a non-inlined function.

Comment: Hasn't been true for a long time. Functions can be inlined at link time in modern versions of gcc and I think MSVC.

Comment: @BoBTFish : Another thing I learnt then. You learn the most when you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, if you want your complex function be inserted inline, you must specify the `inline` keyword too.
In practice, use `__forceinline` keyword (on windows, `__always_inline` on linux) otherwise the compiler will ignore the keyword if there is a lot of instructions.

Comment: Thank you for these two keywords. Compiled will be the first wrote equivalent function, or will functionInline also not be inlined (if not used the __forceinline or __always_inline keywords but only the inline keyword)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all inline function is just a directive to the compiler. It is not guaranteed that compiler will do the inlining.

Secondly, when you specify a function as inline, it tells compiler two things

1) Function might be a candidate for inlining. Whether it is going to be inlined is not guaranteed
2) This function has internal linkage. That is, function will be visible only in the translation unit it is compiled. This internal linkage is guaranteed irrespective of whether the function is actually inlined or not.

In you case, functionInline is specified as inline but functionComplex is not. functionComplex has external linkage. Compiler will never do the inlining of function with external linkage.

So, a plain answer to your question is "No" a normal (function without inline keyword and defined outside class)function will never be inlined